# Why does the author add key(task) for the items function in LazyColumn?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

The Code A is from the offical sample [project](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-compose-codelabs/blob/main/AnimationCodelab/finished/src/main/java/com/example/android/codelab/animation/ui/home/Home.kt).

I don't understand why the author need to add  `key(task)` for the `items` function in `LazyColumn`, could you tell me?

I think the Code B can work well and it's simple.

**Code A**

```
val allTasks = stringArrayResource(R.array.tasks)
val tasks = remember { mutableStateListOf(*allTasks) }
...
items(count = tasks.size) { i ->
                val task = tasks.getOrNull(i)
                if (task != null) {
                    key(task) {
                        TaskRow(
                            task = task,
                            onRemove = { tasks.remove(task) }
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
```

**Code B**

```
 ... 
 items(tasks) { task ->
                  TaskRow(
                       task = task,
                        onRemove = { tasks.remove(task) }
                  )
            }
```

Comment: It prevents unnecessary recompositions. If the state passed in `key` hasn't changed, the content won't be recomposed.

Comment: @ArpitShukla `items()` already uses the whole item as key by default

Comment: @Joffrey IIRC it uses the item position as the key by default and not the actual item. [Reference](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/lists#item-keys)

Comment: @ArpitShukla my bad, I actually checked the code itself, but read it the wrong way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keys in general are used to avoid unnecessary recompositions. If you have a list of items, and some items are reordered, Compose will find existing components in the composition based on their key and reorder them accordingly instead of recomposing all of them.

That said, `items()` already supports a `key` parameter. So code A could indeed be simplified this way if the tasks in the list are non-nullable:

```kotlin
items(tasks, key = { it }) { task ->
    TaskRow(
        task = task,
        onRemove = { tasks.remove(task) },
    )
}
```

But code B would use the items' positions instead of the items themselves as key by default, which is not desirable.

Disclaimer: I'm no expert in JetPack Compose